# Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "tags"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-props

I am using a Vue.js component `vue-tags-input`. I want to edit the tags that are stored in the db in the following format 1,2,3,4,5,6.

I split the data by `,` and I push the values onto the tags array.

```js
var tags_split = this.resources[index]['tags'].split(',')
for (var item in tags_split){
  this.tags.push(tags_split[item]);
}

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    tags: [],
    tag: '',
```

The element is populated correctly in my form :

```
<vue-tags-input
  v-model="tag"
  :tags="tags"
  @tags-changed="updateTags"
/>
```

But I get the following error:

```
vue.js:634 [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: custom validator check failed for prop "tags". found in

---> <VueTagsInput> at vue-tags-input/vue-tags-input.vue
       <Root>
```

How is the prop meant to be defined in this case?

Regards Danny.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`tags` should be an array of objects, each with a `text` property.

Docs: http://www.vue-tags-input.com/#/api/props
Source: https://github.com/JohMun/vue-tags-input/blob/32b8f552eaf2eb477b2c97d69a0af5b7ddcb94fc/vue-tags-input/vue-tags-input.props.js#L6

It isn't immediately clear to me why you aren't getting a console warning of `'Missing property "text"'`.

So this:

```js
this.tags.push(tags_split[item]);
```

should be:

```js
this.tags.push({ text: tags_split[item] });
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialize vue instance with an empty tags array. In loop, you assign push to this.tags in the context of window. This means window. Remove the loop and change data declaration to:

```
data() {
    return {
         tags: tags_split
    } 
}
```

Then the vue instance will be able to access the value of tags.

Comment: Sorry I am a little confused by your answer. Assigning tags_split to tags I get an undefined error

Comment: @DannyYounes The code sample in the question shows `tags_split` being defined immediately before you create the Vue instance. My guess would be that the question is misleading and the first section of code is actually inside a method of the Vue instance.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. I fixed it by adding `"tiClasses":["ti-valid"]`

in your case, `this.tags.push({ "text": tags_split[item], "tiClasses": ["ti-valid"] });`

found from here http://www.vue-tags-input.com/#/start